# Eclipse ADT - unhandled loop exception while xml editting

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, adt

I have an issue with Eclipse Indigo SR2 + ADT 18.0. 
Eclipse start refreshing multiple times when I change anything in xml file (e.g.: width, weight, position, adding or removing any element from xml and etc.)
This refreshing looks like blinking of top panel with buttons of changing geometrical params (gravity, weight, ...).

If during this refreshing you try to change another element then Eclipse crashes with a message
"unhandle loop exception". 
After restarting Eclipse the project loads OK without losing last data.

This results in very long waiting after changing any elements in xml.

I remember that in some previous versions of ADT (or Eclipse) there was no such issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is gone when I've updated ADT to version 20